# Hide Django's staticfiles from GitHub stats

Tags: django, git, github, heroku, deployment

To understand what I'm talking about, I call GitHub stat this line:

[image: GitHub stats]

---

I have my Django project on GitHub [repository](https://github.com/persik-dev/LibraLive) and, I use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to deploy this project. To deploy my project to `Heroku`, I need first to run `python manage.py collectstatic` that will generate a lot of CSS and JS like on screenshot above.

I want to hide this folder `not ignore`, because `Heroku` needs it to work properly.

---

UPD 1:

So, I created new branch called `debug`. `debug` branch is identical with `master`, but, without `staticfiles` folder. And when i start `Heroku` with this branch, as i said, it gives me an `500 Server Error`. Ofcourse, I runned `python manage.py collectstatic` before start.

---

UPD 2:

After restarting all `Heroku` dynos (`heroku ps:restart` in `CLI`), all works fine without pre compiled `staticfiles`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> To deploy my project to Heroku, I need first to run python manage.py collectstatic

is *not true*. Heroku will run collectstatic for you when you deploy. You do not need to run it before deploying, and you definitely do not need to add the destination directory to git.

Comment: well, at least for me. because, I can turn `DEBUG` to `False` only if I will push collected static from my local machine

Comment: Why? What happens if you don't? Show the error. And your STATIC settings. Have you installed Whitenoise or django-heroku?

Comment: It shows: `500 Server error`. You can view all my files and settings in my github. there is link in question to it.

Comment: about `collectstatic`. probably, I would try to run it again within `heroku run bash` soon. will update post when i try

Comment: Please read [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets). Also, you seem to have enabled django-storages to upload your static files - and not just your media files - to S3, which contradicts what you're saying here.